# Swift/Firebase sorting

Tags: sorting, firebase, tableview, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently experiencing some issues regarding table view sorting from firebase. What I am trying to achieve is to list 5 different price tiers in a table view, all named (tier1, tier5, tier12, tier24, tierPermanent) - each containing a value (the price).

However, while fetching these values from the database, I find it rather difficult to show these in a table view - both containing text (the time) and the price tiers. What I am doing now, is that I am using observeEventType to display all the values, and then store each value in a dictionary. After that I append it to an array of dictionaries of type [[String:String]].

What I am struggling with, is to display this in a descending order in a table view. Please take note that all of these 5 values are optional, and therefore they might not contain any value - so instead of showing a value on the very first row, and a blank cell at the second, and then a new value on the third row - I want it to display descending compared to the values. (The permanent value will always be on top if it contains a value, or else tier24 will be on top, or else tier12.). For each cell.

I know I would access the unique value with cell.nameLabel.text = cell[indexPath.row]["tier.."] as? String - but the problem is that I need to have some sort of ordering, and make sure the data isn't displayed twice. (order with both key and value - to display both key and value in the same cell.).

Any ideas on how I would approach this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of describing your code, post the [minimal, complete code that reproduces your problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

There's really not enough data to fully address the question but how about this:

A Firebase structure:

```
tiers
  -Y0998uas9j
    tier_type: tier_24
    time: 20160705130100
    sort_order: 1
  -Ykja9s9js9
    tier_type: tier_05
    time: 20160705130300
    sort_order: 3
  -Yukl9jh8sj
    tier_type: tier_permanent
    time: 20160705130500
    sort_order: 0
```

tiers have a sort order to keep them in the correct order.

```
tier_permanent = 0
tier_24 = 1
tier_12 = 2
tier_05 = 3
tier_01 = 4
```

and some code to read them in and keep the sorted, descending:

```
    var myArray = [[String:String]]()
    let tiersRef = self.myRootRef.child("tiers")
    tiersRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

        for child in snapshot.children {
            var dict = [String: String]()
            dict["fbKey"] = child.key as String
            dict["tier_type"] = child.value["tier_type"] as? String
            dict["timestam"] = child.value["time"] as? String
            dict["sort_order"] = child.value["sort_order"] as? String
            myArray.append(dict)
        }

        myArray.sortInPlace( {$0["sort_order"] < $1["sort_order"]} )

        self.mySuperTableView.reloadData()

        for dict in myArray { //meh, print them so show they are sorted
            print(dict)
        }
    })
```

This addresses: keeping them sorted, descending, and if the tires are not present in the database, they will obviously not be read in.

The issue is though, it's unclear from he question the correlation between the tier names and the value (time?). I'll update once more information has been presented.

Comment: Thanks for your very well written and explained answer - however, I solved my problem by creating 5 separate unique table view cell classes. But again, thank you very much!